# Java: Displaying Load Balance into table

Tags: java

I have a problem with this code, I don't know why it doesn't come up with the designated task: display the load balance into table instead of graph. There's no error with this code, so, any advice to solve the problem would be a big help. Here it is the code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class LoadBalance extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JTable jt;

public LoadBalance(RandomQueue<Queue<Integer>> servers, double[] lengths) {
    jt = new JTable();
    jt.setBounds(50,50,200,230);
    JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(jt);
    this.add(js);
    this.setSize(300,400);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int m = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int s = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    // Create server queues.
    RandomQueue<Queue<Integer>> servers = new RandomQueue<Queue<Integer>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        servers.enqueue(new Queue<Integer>());
    }

    // Assign an item to a server
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

        // Pick a random server, update if new min.
        Queue<Integer> min = servers.sample();
        for (int k = 1; k < s; k++) {
            Queue<Integer> queue = servers.sample();
            if (queue.length() < min.length()) min = queue;
        }

        // min is the shortest server queue
        min.enqueue(j);
    }

    int i = 0;
    double[] lengths = new double[m];
    for (Queue<Integer> queue : servers) {
        lengths[i++] = queue.length();

    }
    new LoadBalance(servers, lengths);
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get the better help you should properly state your problem along with the errors/exceptions you are getting.

Comment: In `LoadBalance` you are not using any of the parameters pass in.

Comment: @UsamaAmjad He mentioned that the code doesn't throw an error.

Comment: What do you see when you use your debugger?

Comment: You need to build a model of the data which the `JTable` can use to display it.  See [How to use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details